# Cómo mostrar siempre decimales usando ROUND en PHP y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

cuento con la siguiente sentencia para lograr adquirir el 70% de 2 números, pero deseo que me muestre los decimales cuando el resultado sea `10,0`, `14,0` `20,0` o afines, ya que solo me muestra el decimal cuando el resultado es `10,1`, `14,2`, `19,8`, etc

```
$ap_70 = (round(($ap_1+$ap_2)/2)*0.70);
```

Answer (score 3):

Suena a que el camino es usar [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). El segundo parámetro indica cuántos decimales mostrar:

```
echo number_format(round(3.25 * 0.734, 2), 2)."<br>";
```

De paso, a [`round`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) también hay que decirle cuántas cifras significativas usar, o siempre va a mostrar cero. Supondría que ese código que tienes siempre está redondeando sin decimales...

Comment: Muchas gracias AlfaBravo logré lo que necesitaba con los indicado...

Comment: @AlbertoCarrasquero súper! \m/